# How Can I Tell NHibernate To Treat An FK Empty String As NULL?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working off a legacy database with some "interesting" structures.  I have a table "Operation" with a nullable string column called "PersonnelID".  This column points to a table called "Personnel" with an integer primary key column.  NHibernate has no problem when the PersonnelID column is either an integer represented as a string or NULL, but it blows up when that column contains an empty string (or anything else for that matter.  While this makes sense, I'd like to make it smart enough to recognize when a "PersonnelID" value can be used to load the related Personnel and when to treat the value as garbage.  Where would I inject my logic?  Seems like a IUserType, but not quite.

Comment: can you run a sql-query to clean up the garbage once? like an updatescript or something

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `not-found="ignore"` attribute on the many-to-one. From the documentation:

> not-found (optional - defaults to exception): Specifies how foreign
>   keys that reference missing rows will be handled: ignore will treat a
>   missing row as a null association.